# Do dangerous thing, if fails, try to fix it and do again. If it still fails, give up

Tags: perl

I am looking for the nice form of

```
if (! write_to_file($data) )
{
    open_this_file($file_name)
    write_to_file($data) or die "Cant write to $file_name" ;
}
```

it looks very unclear, is not it? How to write it self-explaining?

Comment: are $data and $file_name two different files?  and what exactly do you mean by 'self-explaining?'?

Comment: @xoid You could change the `if (! foo())` to `if (not foo())` or `unless (foo())`, but I can't see the real question here.

Comment: @amon : The way I see the question, the OP wants a more elegant way to  write the same logic.

Answer (score 7):

#### "Do `or` fix & do `or` die!"

Assuming `write_to_file( $data )` returns false upon failure:

```
   write_to_file( $data )
or do { open_this_file( $file_name ); write_to_file( $data ) }
or die "Can't write to $file_name";
```

You could rewrite it without the `do` block as well thanks to operator precedence. The comma between `open_this_file` and `write_to_file` has a higher precedence than `or`, so the effect is the same as the `do` block:

```
   write_to_file( $data )
or open_this_file( $file_name ), write_to_file( $data )
or die "Can't write to $file_name";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for my $try (1..$num_tries) {
    last if write_to_file($data);
    die '...' if $try == $num_tries;
    open_this_file($file_name)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
open_this_file($file_name) if not write_to_file($data);
write_to_file($data) or die "Cant write to $file_name";
```

Doesn't make much of a difference, but its cleaner, as you wanted..

Or you can use this one-liner: -

```
write_to_file($data) or open_this_file($file_name) and 
                        write_to_file($data) or die "Cant write to $file_name";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sub is_open { return (tell($handle) != -1); }

open_this_file($file_name) if not is_open($handle);
write_to_file($data)       or die "Cant write to $file_name" ;
```

where `$handle` is the file handle.